# Search exact keywords

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a search script that searches cars in a database and matches ALL keywords input by user. If I leave keywords text box empty and search I get results but if I input any keywords I get no results.

```
$search_keywords = $_POST['search_keywords'];
$terms =  $search_keywords;

$items = explode(' ',$terms);
$types = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $types[] = "'title' LIKE '%{$item}%'";
        $types[] = "'exterior_colour' LIKE '%{$item}%'";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM list_car WHERE ";
    $sql .= implode(" && ", $types) . " ORDER BY 'title'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, getPagingQuery($sql, $rowsPerPage));
```

UPDATE:

Works now i have changed it but if i search `Toyota hilux dfkjodsgfudsugfdsgfgfgfdgfdg` all the `Toyota hilux` will appear but `dfkjodsgfudsugfdsgfgfgfdgfdg` is garbage which is not listed in the database i want it to match ALL keywords not just one or more.

```
$search_keywords = $_POST['search_keywords'];
$terms =  $search_keywords;

$items = explode(' ',$terms);
$types = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $types[] = "`title` LIKE '%{$item}%'";
        $types[] = "`exterior_colour` LIKE '%{$item}%'";
    }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM list_CAR WHERE ";
    $sql .= implode(" || ", $types) . "";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, getPagingQuery($sql, $rowsPerPage)) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Try to delete the `%` at the beginning of your query.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson sql injection attack

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($link, getPagingQuery($sql, $rowsPerPage)) or die(mysqli_error($link));` to see where your syntax errors are.

Comment: *"A" is for Apple, "J" is for Jacks*

Comment: @Dagon You'd need a pretty good grade of HSS for a seringe to inject that robot with.

Comment: You're also overwriting your array.

Comment: @Fred -ii-  There are no syntax errors

Comment: probably because it's never making it there. This `ORDER BY 'title'` should be throwing you one. Well.... someone gave you an answer below.

Comment: Yes i changed them to backticks but still getting no results

Comment: You should update what you currently have. Also as noted in answer below `and` everything will probably result in no results because that requires every data point is present in every column..

Comment: You want it to match at least one of the pairings?

Comment: So for example title = "Toyota hilux black 1994". if i search "Toyota dfdfdf" that database entry will show up in results. i want it to match all keywords exactly so if i input "toyota hilux blue" i dont want it to show the "Toyota hilux black 1994"

Comment: Okay, posted two approaches. Post if you have questions or issues (prepared statement probably won't work on the first go. Take a look here for more about them, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: Questions/issues with answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
$terms = $search_keywords = 'Toyota hilux dfkjodsgfudsugfdsgfgfgfdgfdg';
$items = explode(' ',$terms);
$types = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM list_CAR WHERE ";
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $sql .= " (`title` LIKE ? or `exterior_colour` LIKE ?) and ";
    $params[] = '%' . $item . '%';
    $params[] = '%' . $item . '%';
}
if(!empty($params)) {
     $sql = rtrim($sql, ' and ');
     $result = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
     foreach($params as $param) {
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "s", $param);
     }
     mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
} else {
     die('No params built...WHY');
}
```

Note I'm using untested `mysqli` prepared statements, I haven't built the parameterized queries procedurally in `mysqli`, I base this approach off user comments on the [manual's page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

This should give a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM list_CAR 
WHERE  
(`title` LIKE ? or `exterior_colour` LIKE ?) and  
(`title` LIKE ? or `exterior_colour` LIKE ?) and  
(`title` LIKE ? or `exterior_colour` LIKE ?)
```

Which will require each keyword is present in the title or the color list.

If you were to keep it unprepared, which is unrecommended and poor practice, it would be..

```
$terms = $search_keywords = 'Toyota hilux dfkjodsgfudsugfdsgfgfgfdgfdg';
$items = explode(' ',$terms);
$types = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $types[] = " (`title` LIKE '%{$item}%' or `exterior_colour` LIKE '%{$item}%') ";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM list_CAR WHERE ";
    $sql .= implode(" and ", $types) . "";
echo $sql;
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM list_CAR WHERE  
(`title` LIKE '%Toyota%' or `exterior_colour` LIKE '%Toyota%')  and  
(`title` LIKE '%hilux%' or `exterior_colour` LIKE '%hilux%')  and 
 (`title` LIKE '%dfkjodsgfudsugfdsgfgfgfdgfdg%' or `exterior_colour` LIKE '%dfkjodsgfudsugfdsgfgfgfdgfdg%')
```

Comment: Thanks chris85 that worked perfectly how i wanted it to

Answer (score 2):

You should use `OR` (`||`) instead of `AND` (`&&`) . As it is, your search term must match against all fields:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM list_car WHERE ";
$sql .= implode(" OR ", $types) . " ORDER BY 'title'";
```