# Dynamic mysql query in prepared

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating dynamic query in PHP.

```
#$id = $_POST[id];
#$field1 = $_POST[field1];
#$field2 = $_POST[field2];
#$field3 = $_POST[field3];

$id = "id";
$field1 = "222";
$field2 = "787";
$field3 = "4444444";

$whereArr = array();
if($id != "") $whereArr[] = "id = {$id}";
if($field1 != "") $whereArr[] = "field1 = {$field1}";
if($field2 != "") $whereArr[] = "field2 = {$field2}";
if($field3 != "") $whereArr[] = "field3 = {$field3}";

$whereStr = implode(" AND ", $whereArr);

$query = "Select * from assignments WHERE {$whereStr}";
echo $query;
```

It is working fine.

```
Select * from assignments
WHERE id = id AND field1 = 222 AND field2 = 787 AND field3 = 4444444
```

I am getting the correct query but mysql is no longer maintained. So, I am using prepared statement like this.

```
$firstname = 'Patrick';
$lastname = 'Allaert';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

$cond = array();
$params = array();

if (!empty($firstname)) {
    $cond[] = "firstname = ?";
    $params[] = $firstname;
}

if (!empty($lastname)) {
    $cond[] = "lastname = ?";
    $params[] = $lastname;
}

if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
echo $query;
```

**Problem is how can i bind the parameters.**

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
```

Thanks for your advise.

Comment: why you are using array !?

Comment: You can pass `$params` in the execute. (also `$email` isn't in your code currently but I assume this is just a shortened version).

Comment: @chris85 It would be helpful if you give an example/

Comment: @CalculatingMachine posted an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the array into the `execute` and it will bind the values of that array.

```
$firstname = 'Patrick';
$lastname = 'Allaert';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

$cond = array();
$params = array();

if (!empty($firstname)) {
    $cond[] = "firstname = ?";
    $params[] = $firstname;
}

if (!empty($lastname)) {
    $cond[] = "lastname = ?";
    $params[] = $lastname;
}

if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

You can see this approach on the manual as example #3. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Mysqli approach:

```
$firstname = 'Patrick';
$lastname = 'Allaert';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$cond = array();
$params = array();
if (!empty($firstname)) {
    $cond[] = "firstname = ?";
    $params[] = $firstname;
}
if (!empty($lastname)) {
    $cond[] = "lastname = ?";
    $params[] = $lastname;
}
if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
if(!empty($params)) {
    $n = count($params);
    $a_params[] = & str_repeat('s', $n);
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $a_params[] = & $params[$i];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $a_params);
}
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris85. I will check and let you know. Voted Up.

Comment: Oh, this is using `mysqli`, not `pdo`, right? If so might want to look at this approach, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574016/search-exact-keywords/32575326#32575326. The `execute` function isn't noted as taking the arrays as bound parameters in the mysqli manual (although others have said it does).

Comment: I checked that question but i didn't found anyware bind parameter. If you explain bit more then it would be great.

Comment: The answer, not the question. It starts at line 10 `foreach($params as $param) {`and you'll have to use object style over procedural.

Comment: I tried to understand it but its quite tough for me to understand. Looking for other way.

Comment: I am getting Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement. Any advise on this.

Comment: Also your answer seems to work with PDO not with mysqli.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Okay, updated with tested code. Altered code from: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli. Not sure if it is my local outdated PHP version or why previous examples used aren't working..

Answer (score 0):

No need for arrays in your script

you can use script like below:

```
$where = " 1=1";
if($id != "") $where .= " and id = $id ";
if($field1 != "") $where .= " and field1 = '" . $field1 . "' ";
if($field2 != "") $where .= " and field2 = '" . $field2 . "' ";
if($field3 != "") $where .= " and field3 = '" . $field3 . "' ";

$query = "Select * from assignments WHERE $where";
echo $query;
```

Comment: This is **NOT** how prepared statements work. This also is invalid SQL.

Comment: why its invalid statement @chris85 ?

Comment: `$firstname = 'Patrick';` and `$lastname = 'Allaert';` so they are strings they need to be quoted. The question is about prepared statements though so this whole approach is wrong. or if you are trying to rewrite the first chunk of code it is unnecessary because `It is working fine.`. The OP is updating to prepared statements which are more secure.

Comment: do you see $firstname & $lastname in my answer ?
it is just fields.. he can but quotes wherever he use string ... this script is working 100%

Comment: The question is about the second chunk of code **not** the first. This code will fail. ($field1 would presumably be $firstname)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try and let you know. But actually this is not the answer i am looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is a dangerous answer and not a prepared approach, nor the approach one should be taking (Good morning SQL injections).